# Is it possible, in C#, to store execution commands in a List and carry out in a loop

Tags: c#, list

Lets say I have the following lines of code:

```
 callBacksToSend.Send(vaProxy, "a1", "b1");
 callBacksToSend.Send(vaProxy, "a2", "b2", c2);
 callBacksToSend.Send(vaProxy, "a3", "b3");
 callBacksToSend.Send(vaProxy, "a4", "b4");
.
.
.
 callBacksToSend.Send(vaProxy, "an", "bn", cn);
```

How can I store all the above in a LIST or array or Dictionary, and run in a loop?
I need this because I want to run a check after each command is carried out.

Comment: What's the signature for the Send method ?

Comment: Does the Send() method accept an object as well as parameters? If so you can store the objects in a List<T> and foreach through them.

Comment: You may be looking for the "Command" design pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a list of **delegates** I suggest to use a list of **arguments**

```
var args = new[] { new[] { "a1", "b1" }, new[] { "a2, "b2" }, ... };
foreach(var arg in args)
    callbacks.Send(vaProxy, arg[0], arg[1]);
```

If the `args` may vary you can also extract some class for them:

```
class Arg
{
    string Item1;
    string Item2;
    int Item3;
    ...
}
```

Now create a list of those and loop them:

```
var args = new[] { new Arg { ... }, new Arg { ... }, ...};
foreach(var arg in args)
    callbacks.Send(vaProxy, arg);
```

Comment: This may be a cleaner approach if you are always calling the same overload of the same function.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that.
What is my arguments for the different overload are not all strings?
In my case string and/or integers.
Actually I have 4 overloads:

{string} 

{string, string}

{string, string, int}

[string, string, int, int}

Comment: @dandan Then you should go for extracting a class for the argzments as suggested within the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use lambda expressions to do something like this

```
var actions = new List<Action>() {
   () => foo.Send(vaProxy, "a1", "b1"),
   () => foo.Send(vaProxy, "a2", "b2", c2)
   //....
};

foreach (var a in actions) {
    a();
    Console.WriteLine("did an action!");
}
```

Comment: There isn’t really a point in having a list of actions/delegates, as every action/delegate is a MulticastDelegate, i.e. every Action is already a list of actions. You could just do `Action action = null; action += () => foo.Send(vaProxy, "a1", "b1"); a += () => foo.Send(vaProxy, "a2", "b2", c2);`.

Comment: If you want to do something between each action in a loop then multicast delegates does not help